# Suppose A = {1,3,7,11} and B = {3,7,12} . Calculate the following showing the step-by-step process of your calculations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Suppose A = {1,3,7,11} and B = {3,7,12} . Calculate the following showing the step-by-step process of your calculations

a) |A ∪ B|

b) |A| + |B| - |A ∩ B|

c) A X B

Not sure if I'm doing these right.. would a) be:

{1,3,7,11,12} ? and what steps would I show? what is there to show?

Comment: No, you're missing the $|\cdots|$ signs. You have found $A\cup B$ correctly, but the question is asking for $|A\cup B|$, which is the _number of elements_ in $A\cup B$.

Comment: Ahh.. so |1,3,7,11,12| = 5 ? @HenningMakholm

Comment: x @user: Well, yes, the _result_ is $5$, but writing $|1,3,7,11,12|$ is not meaningful. The thing between the bars must be a _set_, so you want to write $|\{1,3,7,11,12\}|$ as one of your steps.

Comment: so |{1,3,7,11,12}| = 5 is my final solution correct?

Comment: x @user: Depends on how many steps the grader is expecting to see. It might be safer to write a few more: $$ |A\cup B| = |\{1,3,7,11\}\cup\{3,7,12\}| = |\{1,3,7,11,12\}| = 5 $$

Comment: Ahh I see. Also is |A∪B|=|{1,3,7,11}∪{3,7,12}| known as the "cardinalality " of the set |A U B|? what are the | symbols supposed to be representing here? Abs value or what? @HenningMakholm

Comment: @user3325915 Yes, it is the cardinality, which means the number of elements in the set. $|\{a\}| = 1$, $|\{a, b\}| = 2$, and so on.

Comment: @mrp any Idea on how I would do |A| + |B| - |A ∩ B| ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) $|A \cup B| = |\{1,3,7,11,12\}| = 5$

b) $|A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = |\{1,3,7,11\}| + |\{3,7,12\}| - |\{3,7\}| = 4 + 3 - 2 = 5$

c) $A \times B = \{(a,b) \; | \; a \in A \text{ and } b \in B\} = \{(1,3),(1,7),(1,12),(3,3),(3,7),(3,12),(7,3),(7,7),(7,12),(11,3),(11,7),(11,12)\}$

Also, we see that $|A \times B| = 12$, and in general $|A \times B| = |A| \cdot |B|$.

Comment: Wow I cant believe how simple that was. Thank you for the explanation!